# Show in a loop how many times the post was viewed

Tags: wordpress, function, loops

How can I show in a loop how many times the post was seen?
I have this function but I can't put it in the loop or if you have another way of doing it please let me know. Thanks.

```
function eye_PostViews($post_ID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count'; 
    $count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, true);  
    if($count == ''){
        $count = 1;      
        delete_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key);       
        add_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, '1');
        return $count . ' View';  
    }else{
        $count++;     
        update_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, $count);   
        if($count == '1'){
        return $count . ' View'; 
        }
        else {
        return $count . ' Views'; 
        }
    }
}

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$post_views=eye_PostViews($post_ID);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();?>
   the_title();Num views: $post_views;?>
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use plugin yet existing: [Post views counter](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/)